# What RTCM3 messages are needed for RTK/DGPS?

Tags: dgps, rtkgps+

I am using a U-Blox F9P as a base station and sending RTCM3 corrections over packet radio to another F9P as the rover.  I am currently sending 1005, 1074, 1077, 1084, 1087, and 1230.  The rover will get a RTK Float pretty quickly, but will struggle to get and maintain an RTK fix.  This seems to make the altitude unreliable.

Are there other messages I should be using to ensure a more rapid/stable fix and to get more reliable altitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two SkyTraq PX1122R units, and I use messages 1005, 107x, 108x, 109x, and 110x without too many issues. You may need to use something like 1007 with your antenna details. Make sure your antenna is as high as possible but unaffected by wind as much as is practical. Make sure your base station location is as accurate as possible too, if you have the time, a PPP query a week after gathering the initial data will help.